# Remove KVO observer issue

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a menu controller that connected with view controller over weak reference. View controller have srong reference to menu controller.

Menu controller observes some property of collection view in view controller.
When menu controller deallocated, I call `[self.viewController.collectionView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath];` But in this place self.viewController is already nil.

In what place should I remove KVO observer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you do it in other way around.
You should add observer in view controller, not in menu controller:

```
[object addObserver:menuController forKeyPath:@"openingBalance" ...];
```

Just pass menu controller as an argument to `addObserver:` method and implement the `observeValueForKeyPath:` method in menu controller.

You can remove the observer when you needed (I believe you want to do it in dealloc method), still in view controller, in that scenario when your view controller will be deallocated it remove the observer first.